# AngularJS datatable sorting

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using AngularJS Datatables plugin and I want to sort the table by column. The problem is when I click on a thead cell, everything will disappear. 
I'll attach some code down below. 
I tried to look for topics on the same subject, but I couldn't find anything that would help me. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Created at</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
                <td>{{user.role}}</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-info" ng-click="vm.getUserById(user.id)"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-delete"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('UsersController', function UsersController($scope, UserService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.getUserById = getUserById;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder;
    vm.dtColumnDefs = DTColumnDefBuilder;

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `datatable="ng"` instead of `datatable=""` when using angular-datatables the "angular" way.

angular-datatables the "angular" way doc: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularWay